# Xamarin XAML StaticResource inside another one

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, staticresource

I have a string in my ResourceDictionary in App.xaml.

```
<x:String x:Key="logoEvo">.Images.logoEvo.png</x:String>
```

How can I use it inside another StaticResource like this:

```
<Image Source="{sgat:ImageResource SgatMobileOnline{StaticResource logoEvo} }" />
```

ImageResource's file is:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Internals;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace SgatMobileOnline {

    // You exclude the 'Extension' suffix when using in Xaml markup
    [Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    [ContentProperty("Source")]
    public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension {
        public string Source { get; set; }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
            if (Source == null) {
                return null;
            }
            // Do your translation lookup here, using whatever method you require
            var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source);

            return imageSource;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In App.cs

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <x:String x:Key="logoEvo">test.png</x:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

XAML:

```
<Image Source="{local:ImageResourceExtension logoEvo}" />
```

ImageResourceExtension

```
namespace App1
{
[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
[ContentProperty("Source")]
public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    public string Source { get; set; }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Source == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        string s = Application.Current.Resources[Source] as string;
        // Do your translation lookup here, using whatever method you require

        var assembly = typeof(ImageResourceExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        var assemblyString = assembly.GetName().Name.ToString();
        var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(assemblyString + "." + s);
        return imageSource;
    }
}
}
```

PS:Make sure the image's Build Action as **Embedded Resource**

Comment: Thank you but, do you tried this before post it? 
Because isn't working..

Comment: @Jackpot21 I have tried it and works perfectly . Please ensure you can access the image via the string

Comment: @Jackpot21 I test in uwp project and the image is placed at the root folder

Comment: Thank you, but I have the image inside the PCL project, not into the single platform project.